# Different length of data in distance correlations

Tags: r, correlation, independence, distance-covariance

I would like to use a distance correlation/covariance analysis to detect (non-linear) dependencies in my data in R. However, my data has a lot of NAs so, after filter them (because dcor/dcov implementation in R does not face with NAs), I obtain vectors with different lengths.

I read the distance correlations could lead with different length vectors. However, I have this error:

```
dcor.test(variable1[which(!is.na(variable1))],variable2[which(!is.na(variable2))], R=50)
  Error in dcov.test(x, y, index = 1, R) : Sample sizes must agree

DCOR(dat$Demográficas.Age.[which(!is.na(dat$Demográficas.Age.))],dat$Demográficas.Situación.en.el.banco.[which(!is.na(dat$Demográficas.Situación.en.el.banco.))])
  Error in DCOR(dat$Demográficas.Age.[which(!is.na(dat$Demográficas.Age.))],  :
```

Sample sizes must agree

```
length(variable1[which(!is.na(variable1))]) = 4000
length(variable2[which(!is.na(variable2))]) = 1000
```

It is not possible to compare different length vectors also with distance correlation? How can I deal with that?

Thank you so much!

Here are some principal references of distance correlation:
Szekely et al.(2007): http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.225.9216&rep=rep1&type=pdf
The package of R I am using: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/energy/energy.pdf

UPDATE

I tried with bcdcor (bias-corrected distance correlation), implemented in Energy and Rfast packages, and he can work with different length vectors. However, I can't understand why and how this "bias-correction" affect in the analysis/results. Some ideas?

Comment: I think no. Distance covariance/correlation can handle different number of variables (dimensions) in the being correlated two sets, by they should have the same  cardinality. Try to impute missing observations.

Comment: Hi @ttnphns, thank for your answer! I updated the post with the results of the bcdcor. Do you know something about that?